# Making ROCs curves

Tags: r, roc

I am trying to plot the ROC curve for a diagnostic test. I believe I got the correct values, but my ROC is so smooth. Do I need to randomly generate my values 100 times to get a jagged ROC curve? I cannot figure out how to do this

```
dat <- as.table(matrix(c(8,32,2, 30), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE))
colnames(dat) <- c("Dis+","Dis-")
rownames(dat) <- c("Test+","Test-")

rval <- epi.tests(dat, conf.level = 0.95)
print(rval); summary(rval)

predicted_prob<-predict(lab_file2$risk_score,type="response")
roccurve <- roc(lab_file2$complication, lab_file2$risk_score)

plot(roccurve)
```

Comment: When I run your code I get an error: Error in epi.tests(dat, conf.level = 0.95) : 
  could not find function "epi.tests". Please make sure that we can reproduce your code.

Comment: Same comment as @Calimo. When using the `epiR` library to accomodate for the `pi.tests`, the next error is: `lab_file2` is not available